# Entity Framework: How to enable migration to get & save data from sql view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity

Is it possible to get and save data from SQL view rather then specifying it on "On Model Creating" in context?

I am using code first Framework approach and want to know if there is any way to save data on "add-migration/update-database" from my another view (I don't want to feed new data in this table as need to keep same value in primary key)

Is it possible to push context to get and feed data in specific table from a view during Migration ?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>().HasData(new Table1 { Table1ID = 1, Title = "Test" });
}
```